# How to write down the rspec to test rescue block.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rescue

I have method like this

```
def className  
  def method_name
    some code  
  rescue  
    some code and error message  
  end  
end
```

So, How to write down the rspec to test rescue block..?

Answer (score 12):

If you want to rescue, it means you expect `some code` to raise some kind of exception.

You can use [RSpec stubs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs) to fake the implementation and force an error. Assuming the execution block contains a method that may raise

```
def method_name
  other_method_that_may_raise
rescue => e
  "ERROR: #{e.message}"
end
```

hook the stub to that method in your specs

```
it " ... " do
  subject.stub(:other_method_that_may_raise) { raise "boom" }
  expect { subject.method_name }.to_not raise_error
end
```

You can also check the rescue handler by testing the result

```
it " ... " do
  subject.stub(:other_method_that_may_raise) { raise "boom" }
  expect(subject.method_name).to eq("ERROR: boom")
end
```

Needless to say, you should raise an error that it's likely to be raised by the real implementation instead of a generic error

```
{ raise FooError, "boom" }
```

and rescue only that `Error`, assuming this is relevant.

---

As a side note, in Ruby you define a class with:

```
class ClassName
```

not

```
def className
```

as in your example.

Comment: Thanks Carletti.
This is very helpful for me to test rescue block.

Comment: It doesn't work when I'm trying to expect method to raise error when it's already rescued by the method.

Answer (score 2):

you can stub with return error

for example you have class with method like this :

```
class Email
  def self.send_email
    # send email
  rescue
    'Error sent email'
  end
end
```

so rspec for raising error is

```
context 'when error occures' do
  it 'should return error message' do
    allow(Email).to receive(:send_email) { err }
    expect(Email.send_email).to eq 'Error sent email brand'
  end
end
```