# Why is valid? not being set to false, after adding an error in my custom validator in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm working on a refactor for some ruby on rails v6 application. I have made a custom validator to test if the string being passed could be parsed into a Date object, like so:

```
class DateFormatValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if options[:fields].any? do |field|
         if record.send(field).nil?
           return true
         end
         unless valid_date?(record.send(field))
           record.errors.add(field, :invalid)
           return false
         end
       end
    end
  end

  def valid_date?(date_string)
    Date.parse(date_string)
    true
  rescue ArgumentError
    false
  end
end
```

It is being called, and it adds the error to the record with the correct key for the field i'm passing. It is being called like so from inside my model:

```
validates_with DateFormatValidator, fields: [:date_of_birth]
```

But, when I ran a test to failed that parser like this:

```
  def test_it_raises_ArgumentError_due_to_invalid_date
    customer = customers(:one)

    assert_raises(ArgumentError) do
      customer.update({date_of_birth: "18/0-8/1989"})
    end
  end
```

Now, the assert_raises is my problem. I would expect to be able to do customer.valid? and since an error has been added to the customer it would return false. But instead, it returns:

```
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong or how to make the valid? turn false when i add an error into the errors obj holding my record??

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999426/how-to-write-down-the-rspec-to-test-rescue-block, this might be solve your issue.

Comment: sorry, that is not what i'm looking for. I need to set valid? to false to keep consistency in my tests

Comment: If you see an error, always post a backtrace as well. Looking at the backtrace may help you to fix your issue by yourself too.